# Operations on file

Tags: c, file

I have some files, say around 5 to 6 files in one folder, I have to write a code in such a way that I should use only one file_pointer and read all the files, one after the other, without closing it. After I read all the files, I should close.

How can I Achieve this ?

Comment: I think this would be resource leaking, you have to close a `FILE*` after you are done with it. You still can use the same variable though for mutiple open/close

Comment: I can not think why would you want to do this. I can understand not closing the files once read could be a requirement, but using just one pointer does not make sense. It's like trying to hold 10 odd things, using just one hand, and not letting go off the previous items while acquiring new ones.

Comment: Most likely this is an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

`fclose` is a good habit, but (from what I understand from the standard) all files are automatically closed when the program exits.

From the standard: **7.19.3 Files**

> If the main function returns to its original caller, or if the exit
>   function is called, all open files are closed (hence all output
>   streams are flushed) before program termination. Other paths to
>   program termination, such as calling the abort function, need not
>   close all files properly.

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the same file pointer without closing files ultimately will work, but it is terrible style and will lead to bad things down the line.

I'd suggest you either use a vector of file pointers (one for each file) or use one pointer but be sure to close it via

> fclose()

before you open the next file.